# Accessing a country list from a mySQL table or from a CSV table

Tags: mysql, html

For a web-register form I need to ask for the country. For this purpose I want to provide a given list with some 300 entries in a `select`element.

What is more fast and makes more sense , accessing a list from a mySQL DB table or from a CSV file ?

Comment: ask clearly what you want, and if possible then post dummy data

Comment: You can use MySQL DB to store those country list.

Comment: well I want to know what is more fast : Accessing a mySQL database table or a CSV file (opening and read out). What is unclear ?

Comment: You can time it. However, be aware of timing 1) may vary depending on how many processes try to read the same resource (file or db) 2) consider other benefits, not just speed 3) consider other methods, such as including the list in php file in html format directly usable from the code, or in a js file, that can be cached by browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try storing the country list as a cached json file, since this list will likely not be changing much. You can just write a script so that whenever your database table of countries is updated, it writes it out to the json file. And you can use local storage to prevent having to redownload the json cache file after the first page load:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // check to see if the list is already cached
    // if not download and store in local storage cache
    if(localStorage.getItem('list_country') === null)
    {
        $.get(
             '/cache/list_country.json'
            ,function(data){
                localStorage.setItem('list_country', JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        );
    }

    // use the stored cache to populate the select list
    $.each($.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('list_country')), function(k, v){
        $('#country').append($('<option>').val(k).text(v));
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="country">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select</option>
</select>
```

**PHP** (to update cache file)

```
// list is key/value pairs from SELECT id, name FROM database table like
$list = array("US"=>"United States","FR"=>"France"); //etc

$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/list_country.json';
$handle = fopen($file_path.$this->cache_file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, json_encode($list));
fclose($handle);
```

**JSON**:

```
{"US":"United States","FR":"France"} // etc
```

Comment: It seems not so easy to say which way is faster doe of different ways to acess such lists. So I accept this answer in terms of what make more sense ...    WebChemist gave dedicated hints how to cache it locally and make it fast to access this way